# How can I reload my jquery datatable after ajax success?

Tags: jquery, error-handling, datatables, reload

I am trying to reload my jquery datatable after successful ajax event:

```
 $(document).on('change', '#select', function(e) {
    var uuid = $( "#form_uuid" ).val();
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    var formData = form.serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
      method:'POST',
      url:'{{ path('forms', { 'slug': output.page.slug }) }}',
      data: {
        "data": formData
      },
      success: function(data){
          table.ajax.reload();  
      }
    });
```

I get the following error message:

> DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Invalid JSON
>   response. For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/1

I tried also to use

```
$('.table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

but I get the same error message.

This is my datatable:

```
  var table = $('.table').DataTable({
    "scrollX": true,
    "data": {{ output.data|raw }},
  });
```

Comment: Did you follow that link and perform the diagnosis they recommend?

Comment: Your code doesn't show how you've set up the DataTable. Perhaps you've missed something. See: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: `ajax.reload()` triggers reloading data from the source, set by the DataTables `ajax` option, most probably you haven't specified one.

Comment: I added my datatable to my question. I am loading data via json

Comment: @Moob Yes, I followed the diagnosis, but there is unfortunately no ajax request shown in the resource list

Comment: I also tested `table.draw();` but didn't work

Comment: In your example you do not appear to be using an [ajax datasource](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax). Look again at [ajax.reload()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()). I would expect to see an ajax option in your invoker. eg: `ajax: "/path/to/data.json"`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
table.fnDraw();
```

or:

```
reloadTable = $('.table').dataTable();
reloadTable.fnDraw();
```

Comment: `table.fnDraw();`worked! But why is this working and `table.draw();` not!